# Smooth scaling a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, scaling

I have a `MovieClip` that contains bitmaps as frames. How can I scale it smoothly, achieving the same effect as with `Bitmap.smoothing` set to `true`?

I also have a `Sprite` that contains `Bitmap`s. I want to achieve the same effect on the `Sprite`, but setting its `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties results in the same problem. I tried setting `smoothing` to `true` on the children `Bitmap` instances, but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: You can check [this article](http://npacemo.com/wordpress/2009/07/31/flash-smoothing-issue/) it will guide you through the magic of smoothing in flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick that you can use to get a smoothing-like effect on a MovieClip is to apply a small **BlurFilter** to it, like:

```
var blurFilter:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(2, 2, BitmapFilterQuality.LOW);
my_mc.filters = [ blurFilter ];
```

Either this, or assign `smoothing=true` for each bitmap inside the MovieClip.